# use require_once at ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want use require_once for my ajax request. But it show error. This is my code.

```
 var val = $('#customers option:selected').val();
 $.post('base/chartval.php', {customer:val},  function(data) {

 });
```

This is my base/chartval.php

```
<?php

require_once 'service.php';

if (isset($_POST)) {

    $customer = $_POST['customer'];

    echo $customer; 

    $service::getColumData($customer);
}
```

This is error which is show when use require_once.

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:2500/dinukanew/base/chartval.php"
```

But  `echo $customer;` is work when remove require line.

service.php file also at base folder. When i remove require_once it can work. But i want to use methods in service.php. Please help me.

Comment: It's good that you're not telling us *what* error you are getting. That way, we all get to make a guess! Engineers *love* to guess.

Comment: Whats your path? `get_include_path` and verify that chartval.php and service.php are located either within the same folder or service within the include path.

Comment: `$service::getColumData` looks like a spelling error? (Maybe you wanted `::getColumnData`?)

Comment: if(!file_exists("service.php"))
  die("not there!");
require_once ...

Answer (score 0):

`require_once` requires an argument to be passed in brackets:

`require_once('service.php')`

Comment: check your service.php then, problem must be there - you must have missed sth like `;`, `{`, `)`, ...

Comment: no. I uset test.php. test.php only has echo 'heloo'; but it not work.

Comment: can you provide any running example? are you sure you wrote `require_once('service.php');` ? have you tried solution provided by muka in comment to your question? what is the exact code of `test.php`?